# Collection has not been initialized when called in async function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function populateList(){
    var _clientContext;
    var _web;
    _clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    _web = _clientContext.get_web();
    var listTitle = "Data1";
    var list = _web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var myquery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    myquery.set_viewXml('valid query');
    var allItems = list.getItems(myquery);
    _clientContext.load(allItems);  
    _clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded()), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    var listEnumerator = this.allItems.getEnumerator(); //this craps out
}
```

I get the error

> "Error: The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested."

Comment: what is the query you are using?

Comment: Have you tried `allItems.getEnumerator();` instead of `this.allItems`?  It might be an issue with the scopes.

Comment: I put a setTimeout around my allItems = list.getItems(myquery); and _clientContext.load(allItems); and it seems to work, now I just need to figure out if I can incorporate a callback on those

Comment: John, you absolutely, one-hundred percent, do not need to use `setTimeout` to make this work...

Comment: John-o you're right. I'm still struggling with this problem. I think there is an issue with the sequence of it loading. I have the call to populateLists inside of an onclick event:  <button ID="retrieveList" onclick="ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(populateList, 'sp.js');return false">Retrieve List</button>

Answer (score 5):

The problem lies with object scope. Try below

```
var allItems;
function populateList(){
    var _clientContext;
    var _web;
    _clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    _web = _clientContext.get_web();
    var listTitle = "Data1";
    var list = _web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var myquery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    myquery.set_viewXml('valid query');
    allItems = list.getItems(myquery);
    _clientContext.load(allItems);  
    _clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    var listEnumerator = allItems.getEnumerator(); //this craps out
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to declare allItems variable outside method then the other way would be to declare allItems inside block but with a 'this' keyword

```
function populateList(){
    var _clientContext;
    var _web;
    _clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    _web = _clientContext.get_web();
    var listTitle = "Data1";
    var list = _web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var myquery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    myquery.set_viewXml('valid query');
    this.allItems = list.getItems(myquery);
    _clientContext.load(this.allItems);  
    _clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    var listEnumerator = allItems.getEnumerator();
}
```